# Prints String with white space in java

Tags: java

Am having a txt file. which is having line like

```
       if(true) return true;
```

I need to get the sub string from preceding spaces that is

```
"         if(true) "
```

and another sub string as

```
" retrun true;  "
```

I am reading this line using scanner class  and assign to a string. from that string am converting it into toCharArray. I have tried using toCharArray[] but the spaces are ignored. How to get the substring from the preceding spaces using toCharArray

kindly anybody help me to get a solution for this issue

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? This sounds like you need a parser or an interpreter, are you trying to evaluate the first `String`?

Comment: use indexof to find the substring index!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use StringReader:

```
String str = "Some String";
int numberOfChars = str.length();
StringReader sr = new StringReader(str);
char[] chars = new char[numberOfChars];
int i = 0, read = 0;

try {
    while ((read = sr.read()) != -1) {
        chars[i] = (char)read;
        i++;
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    // handle the exception
}
```

This will read all the characters, without skipping any of them.

EDIT:
Now that I understand what you are trying to do, I would recommend you to define a grammar for your instructions. In this way you should be able to identify these 2 separate statements or instructions. I would suggest you to use a compiler building tool for that like e.g. [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/).

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. The above answer would be helpful . but I need to split up one statement into two staments one by one. like if(true) followed by return true; in the next line. When am doing like this the line starts with space has been ignored. Kindly give me solution for this. Thanks in advance

Comment: I edited my answer. I hope that it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. Will try the tool and share the output. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have found one solution by using Regular expression for this question. The answer is as follows

```
public class Test{
  public static void main(String[] args){
     String str = "     TestProgram";
     Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s*[a-zA-Z0-9]+$");
     Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
     while(matcher.find()){
         System.out.println(0,matcher.end());
     }
   }
}
```

Thanks